# What does pageContext do in JSP?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp

When I was adding CSS files to my JSP page I came across this code:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css">
```

When I tried to print `pageContext.request.contextPath` in my HTML page, I am getting `/web-customer-tracker` which is my project title.

I referred to the official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) and some other questions here on SO but I am not understanding it.

Can someone explain it in simple words?

Answer (score 0):

In your link, we see that pageContext is an implicit object. It has a getRequest method. A HttpServletRequest object has a getContextPath which returns the portion of the request URI that indicates the context of the request.  It is needed for a server-relative path for the href attribute. A server-relative path begins with a /. If you want to try a page-relative path, then you could try using href="resources/css/style.css".